# Добваление поля в запрос с условием

Tags: sql, sybase

База sybase. Есть запрос к которому надо добавить поле castom_name, из таблицы IPS.tszone. Вся проблема в том что в IPS.tszone может много полей иметь

> t5.zone_alias = cast(t1.RET_ID as CHAR)

И плюс ко всему custom_name может быть два варианта либо char поле(уникальное), либо null. Надо достать именно это уникальное char поле.
Вот изначальный запрос.

```
select 
         t1.Tran, 
         t1.ShedulType
   from PAN.TabelReg as t1
```

Вот измененный

```
   select 
         t1.Tran, 
         t1.ShedulType,
         t5.custom_name 
   from PAN.TabelReg as t1 
   left join IPS.tszone as t5 on t5.zone_alias = cast(t1.RET_ID as CHAR)
```

Comment: покажите структуру таблиц!

Comment: что-то я не вижу отличий измененного запроса

Comment: @teran исправил

Comment: дак что осталось то, отфильтровать `ret_id` которые не `null` ? Без описания таблицы и примеров данных действительно не очень то понятно.

Comment: как это работает: left join IPS.tszone as t5 on t5.zone_alias = cast(t1.RET_ID as CHAR)